# Use of remote config Firebase with iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, data-structures, firebase-remote-config

In **firebase documentation** is written that **Firebase Remote config**

> "Dynamically controls & changes the behavior & appearance of your app
> without republishing".

But in practice, I've seen that you can change values inside your app, but the implementation needs to be done in client code.

So let's say we want to force users to update the app if they don't have the latest version of it:

I can change default values of the version from **Firebase Remote Config** but the check for the version needs to be done on the client code as well, and then the client can show the alert to force the user to update.

So my question is: why do they say that "Fir Rem Config" works "without republishing" when you still need to work on the client code hence republishing the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Dynamically controls & changes the behavior & appearance of your app without republishing".

Means you need to write your implementation such that it depends on the change of a remote value , the example said about force update means that you implement it fully like this in client side

```
 if remoteValue > currentValue {
     // show update alert
 }
```

Then when you need to force update you change the value at firebase config without the need to republish a new version of your app again , it's the same way as calling apis you set something depending on a change of the response values

Comment: thank you for your clarification.
So let's say that we now decide to make all the people update the app if it's not latest version, 
We need to correct the client code to check local vs remote version and adjust accordingly. So we need to publish this change on the client side before being able to correct "remotely" the app's behaviour.
Correct?

Comment: yes this should be set before uploading the app